# Can someone help me figure out a way to prevent an accordion from expanding upwards when the toggle is selected?

Tags: java, toggle, accordion, wrapper

I am having the hardest time with this one... any help is GREATLY appreciated.

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FAQ Accordion</title>
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <!--Google Font-->
    <link href="https://static.showit.co/file/8xjqzk5sTAmLSMIgi-USpQ/63707/tan_-_enigma.woff" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                How would you describe your style?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                What do your wedding packages include?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                Do you photograph LGBTQIA+ couples?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                Do you offer payment plans?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                Do you help with posing?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="wrapper">
            <button class="toggle">
                I’m obsessed! How do I book you?
                <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>answer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Script-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "tan-enigma";
src: url("https://static.showit.co/file/8xjqzk5sTAmLSMIgi-USpQ/63707/tan_-_enigma.woff");
src: url("https://static.showit.co/file/8xjqzk5sTAmLSMIgi-USpQ/63707/tan_-_enigma.woff");
}

*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(16,120,108);
}
.container{
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 1056px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {.container{
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 275px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.toggle{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #C5A05A;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 0;}

.content{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 12px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
    font-family: rubik!important;
}}

.wrapper{
      background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden!important;

}
.toggle,
.content{
    font-family: "tan-enigma",sans-serif;
}
.toggle{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #C5A05A;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 0;

}

 .toggle.selected {
            color: black;
        }

.content{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
    font-family: rubik!important;
}

.wrapper {box-shadow: #E6C8BF;}
button.toggl element.style { color: #C5A05A;}

.wrapper.expanded {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

JAVA:

```
let toggles = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
let contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
let contentHeight = [];

for (let i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    toggles[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (contentHeight[i] === undefined) {
            contentHeight[i] = contentDiv[i].scrollHeight + "px";
        }

        if (contentDiv[i].classList.contains('expanded')) {
            // Collapse the clicked accordion
            contentDiv[i].classList.remove('expanded');
            contentDiv[i].style.height = "0px";
        } else {
            // Collapse other expanded accordions
            for (let j = 0; j < contentDiv.length; j++) {
                if (j !== i) {
                    contentDiv[j].classList.remove('expanded');
                    contentDiv[j].style.height = "0px";
                }
            }

            // Expand the clicked accordion
            contentDiv[i].classList.add('expanded');
            contentDiv[i].style.height = contentHeight[i];

            // Calculate the total expanded content height
            let totalExpandedHeight = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < contentDiv.length; j++) {
                if (j !== i && contentDiv[j].classList.contains('expanded')) {
                    totalExpandedHeight += parseInt(contentHeight[j]);
                }
            }

            // Adjust the scroll position to prevent expanding upwards
            window.scrollBy(0, totalExpandedHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

No matter what I adjust I cannot keep the accordion from expanding upwards once a question is selected and it's causing an awful overlap with the other elements I have in the page design. Is there any way to force this to only expand downwards?

I tried several different wrapper adjustments to no avail.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and rewrite your question to ask an actual question.